# Distance calculation using iphone Core Location data

Tags: iphone, ios4, geolocation

I want to calculate total distance covered by any vehicle using core location.User press start button it will show calculated distance on iphone screen .It also give some updated data after certain period of time.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the didUpdateLocation method and each time the phone gets a new coordinate, calculate the distance from the prior coordinate, add that to a running total and output that total to your label...

it might have a little inaccuracy, because if they were sitting still they could accrue a little distance

Comment: Is there any process or algorithm by that it gives accurate data?

Comment: maybe you could do something like: 1) calculate the distance covered since the last update 2) if it's larger than some threshold [determined by you], add to cumulative distance traveled, else, ignore...